# ¿Cómo vincular la tabla usuarios con empresas en bases de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla de usuarios y empresas, con relación uno a muchos (una empresa tiene varios usuarios).

Pero al realizar un formulario en PHP, un usuario se puede registrar sin necesidad de tener una empresa, entonces la llave foránea que vincula usuario con empresa quedaria `NULL`

**¿Es posible que la llave foránea quede `NULL` o hay otra posibilidad para realizar la vinculación sin que la llave foránea quede `NULL`?**

Comment: Puedes considerar agregar una empresa "0" que sea "SIN EMPRESA" la cual fungiría la función de la empresa sin tenerla.

Comment: Al crear la tabla haz que la llave columna que lleve la clave foranea pueda tomar valor null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082874/how-to-pass-a-null-value-to-a-foreign-key-field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441988/mysql-foreign-key-to-allow-null

Comment: Creo que tu modelo está mal. Teniendo en cuenta la situación que presentas, podrías tener la tabla *Usuarios*, *Empresas* y *UsuariosEmpresas*. Esta ultima con las claves de las dos tablas. Así puedes tener usuarios sin empresas, empresas sin usuarios y empresas con los usuarios que quieras.

Answer (score 3):

La llave foránea puede ser NULL. De la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL essentially implements the semantics defined by MATCH SIMPLE, which permit a foreign key to be all or partially NULL.

Que podría traducirse como:

> MySQL básicamente implementa la semántica definida por MATCH SIMPLE, que permite que una clave foránea sea total o parcialmente NULL.

De hecho, MySQL permite añadir una opción para `ON DELETE` y `ON UPDATE` cuando creas la clave foránea que es `SET NULL`. Cuando seleccionas `SET NULL` y borras/actualizas el registro en la tabla *padre* entonces el valor de la clave foránea se pondrá a NULL (referencia en el enlace de arriba).

En tu caso, que sea NULL no significa que no exista una empresa asociada al cliente, sino que aún no se conoce qué empresa es la que estará asociada. Puee que no sea algo ideal (hay bases de datos que no permiten NULL en claves foráneas), pero personalmente creo que es mejor opción que crear una empresa de pega "Sin empresa" que realmente no es una empresa.